# How to convert console application in web forms in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

I have two classes which I am using to get google analytics. I have code for console application. I want write that code in web forms. How to add in web forms this code ?

How to add this complete code in web form?

I have added .cs class and written below code

```
namespace GoogleAnalyticsAPI_Sample
{
        class GoogleConnector
        {
            public AnalyticsService Service { get; set; }

            public GoogleConnector(string keyPath, string accountEmailAddress)
            {
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmailAddress)
                   {
                       Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
                   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                Service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                    ApplicationName = "NewDemoProject"
                });
            }

            public AnalyticDataPoint GetAnalyticsData(string profileId, string[] metrics, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
            {
                // My Profile ID is : 98196912
                AnalyticDataPoint data = new AnalyticDataPoint();
                if (!profileId.Contains("ga:"))
                    profileId = string.Format("ga:{0}", profileId);

                GaData response = null;
                do
                {
                    int startIndex = 1;
                    if (response != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextLink))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(response.NextLink);
                        var paramerters = uri.Query.Split('&');
                        string s = paramerters.First(i => i.Contains("start-index")).Split('=')[1];
                        startIndex = int.Parse(s);
                    }

                    var request = BuildAnalyticRequest(profileId, metrics, startDate, endDate, startIndex);
                    response = request.Execute();
                    data.ColumnHeaders = response.ColumnHeaders;
                    data.Rows.AddRange(response.Rows);

                }
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextLink));

                return data;
            }

            private DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest BuildAnalyticRequest(string profileId, string[] metrics,
                                                                                DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int startIndex)
            {
                DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = Service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                                                                    endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), string.Join(",", metrics));
                request.StartIndex = startIndex;
                return request;
            }

            public class AnalyticDataPoint
            {
                public AnalyticDataPoint()
                {
                    Rows = new List<IList<string>>();
                }

                public IList<GaData.ColumnHeadersData> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
                public List<IList<string>> Rows { get; set; }
            }
        }
}
```

in another class i have calling that class

```
namespace GoogleAnalyticsAPI_Sample
{
    class StartPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GoogleConnector ga = new GoogleConnector(@"C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\infibeam\NewDemoProject-199399fasfaa.p12", "554818524279-g0erg68fvle5unijrup71efsdfasfd@developer.gserviceaccount.com");

            var nuberOfPageViews = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:9819111", new string[] { "ga:pageviews" },
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];


            Console.WriteLine("page views : {0}\n Session Duration : {1} \n Avg Session Duration : {2}\n Bounce Rate :{3}\n hits: {4}\n Sessions:{5} ", nuberOfPageViews, sessionDuration, avgSessionDuration, bounceRate, sessions, bounces, hits, sessions);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a new proyect as .dll library, then set the code you use in console and compile, you will get a .dll

then open the web forms proyect and add a reference to that .dll

P.D: remember to set the classes as public in you .dll library to grant access.

Comment: Thanks @Veelicus. its worked for me..big problem solved very easily

Comment: Can I design a web form to control inputs needed in my console app? And then print the output as a txt file or csv when converting console app to .dll? I'm with Microsoft Azure.